# Append array value in every iteration

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, datatable

I have data table and i need to set the heading in every iteration.The array contain all headings.

this works properly

```
 $this->table->set_heading("","$name[0]","$name[1]","$name[2]","$name[3]","$name[4]","$name[5]");
```

But i need to set dynamically

```
$cnt=count(name);
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
        //$this->table->set_heading($name[$i],);    
}
```

Any solution for solve this

Comment: You can simply use `$this->table->set_heading("", $name));`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing individual parameters, `set_heading` does accept array. So you can change your code to

```
$this->table->set_heading("", $name);
```

You can find more info here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling accepts an array, but for functions that do not you can use the below technique.

You can use `call_user_func_array`.

```
$args = [""];
$cnt  = count($name);
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i)
  $args[] = $name[$i];
call_user_func_array([$this->table, 'set_heading'], $args);
```

The loop could be a little better too if you don't really care for the index, ie:

```
$args = [""];
foreach($name as $arg)
  $args[] = $arg;
call_user_func_array([$this->table, 'set_heading'], $args);
```

Or, you could just copy the array and shift the first argument onto the array

```
$args = $name;
array_unshift($args, "");
call_user_func_array([$this->table, 'set_heading'], $args);
```

Please also note that surrounding your arguments in double quotes (ie: `"$name[0]"`) while is technically correct and will work, is poor form and lowers performance, just use them directly without the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

if $name is an array of heading strings e.g.

```
$name = array("first", "last", "address", "phone");
```

Then all you need to do is

```
$this->table->set_heading($name);
```